# in_array not working as intended

Tags: php

I am trying to prevent duplicates from occuring in a final array. I am trying to check for duplicates in a list of `$media_candidate` objects and compile them:

```
$iterator = 0;

// ensure items in final array are unique
while ((count($final_array) < $numResults) && ($iterator < count($media_data))) {
    $media_candidate = $media_data[$iterator++];

    if(!in_array($media_candidate['id'], $final_array)){
         $final_array[] = $media_candidate;
    }
}
```

As you can see in a [print out](http://pastebin.com/mPCQQ3Aa) of `$final_array` the last three elements are appearing 3 times with id, `343050519221992426_18478933`. Any ideas as to what's going on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all: You do not truncate the final array, so that all doublettes will end up at the end.

Second: You are reinventing the wheel: Read up on `array_unique()`

**Edit**

Third: After your edit, there is an even easier way:

```
$final_array=array(); 
foreach($media_data as $m) $final_array[$m['id']]=$m;
//You might want the next line or not
$final_array=array_values($final_array);
```

In essence you outsource the uniqueness to the hash keys of the array.

Answer (score 4):

Try with:

```
if(!in_array($media_candidate['id'], $final_array)){
    $final_array[] = $media_candidate['id'];
}
```

With `$final_array[]` you add new element at the end of the array.

Comment: I tried that...didn't work. :/ here's a more broad code snippet http://pastebin.com/DCGyz6LT $media_data contains all possibly non unique items, $final_array should contain unique $media_candidate objects

Answer (score 2):

You are checking `$media_candidate['id']` but inserting `$media_candidate` in `$final_array`

Answer (score 0):

Try array_unique function like this

$final_array = array_unique($media_candidate);